# How to index on Google a YouTube video built by the video/image content in the Wp editor page?

Tags: seo, google-search, wordpress, youtube

I have a problem with Google search on my website. I built my section on the Wp editor page with a "video/image content" type block. I have a section, on the left the title and the text and on the right my YouTube video on click. So this means I have to click on the right section to view the video in full width.

[image: Block type]

[image: Block test]

[image: Video display ap]

[image: Google search issue]

This way Google doesn't seem to index my video, perhaps because the video doesn't load when the page is open and only loads when I click on the section to play the video.

Google suggests moving the video or image content into the viewport. Does this mean that the "video/image content" type block is not displaying the video within the viewport? Did someone have the same issue? Thanks in advance for your help.